# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" - bigIncrements

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I got this error when I change I to `bigIncrements`:

```
.`products` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

my code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->integer('current_buy');
        $table->integer('count');
        $table->text('short_description');
        $table->text('long_description');
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(0);
        $table->string('series');
        $table->integer('max_buy');
        $table->integer('parent_product_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('parent_product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->tinyInteger('admin_seen')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    DB::update("ALTER TABLE products AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;");
}
```

but below code works fine;

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->integer('current_buy');
        $table->integer('count');
        $table->text('short_description');
        $table->text('long_description');
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(0);
        $table->string('series');
        $table->integer('max_buy');
        $table->integer('parent_product_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('parent_product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->tinyInteger('admin_seen')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

   // DB::update("ALTER TABLE products AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using `bigIncrements()` for `id`, to make it work change this:

```
$table->integer('parent_product_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
```

to this:

```
$table->bigInteger('parent_product_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
```